# Normal Ordering and Wick's theorem for bosons under Bogoliubov transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

Consider two sets of bosonic operators $a_i,a^\dagger_j$ and $\tilde{a}_i,\tilde{a}^\dagger_j$ for which the normal rules for normal ordering and Wick's theorem hold. We now have a Bogoliubov transformation, which introduces new operators $b_i,b^\dagger_j$ and $\tilde{b}_i,\tilde{b}^\dagger_j$, according to

$b_i = u_i(\beta)a_i+v_i(\beta)\tilde{a}^\dagger_i$,

$\tilde{b}_i = u_i(\beta)\tilde{a}_i+v_i(\beta)a^\dagger_i$,

which is the thermal Bogoliubov transform in symmetric gauge thermofield dynamics, with $u^2_i(\beta)-v^2_i(\beta)=1$. These new operators also satisfy the canonical bosonic commutation relations as usual.

**Question**

Can one actually show formally, that there exists a normal ordering and Wick's theorem for the operators $b_i,b^\dagger_j$ and $\tilde{b}_i,\tilde{b}^\dagger_j$ as for $a_i,a^\dagger_j$ and $\tilde{a}_i,\tilde{a}^\dagger_j$? Or is the invariance of the bosonic commutation relations under the Bogolibov transformation sufficient for the existence of those properties?

Answer (score 3):

Wick's theorem depends on the Free Hamiltonian. So if you have (as you do in SC) that after the Bogoliubov transformation the Hamiltonian is $\mathcal{H} = \sum_k \omega_k b^{\dagger}_k b_k$ then Wick's theorem holds, with normal ordering 
$$:AB: = AB - \langle AB \rangle_0$$
that is we remove the expectation value for the ground-state. It is crucial that of course the transformed operators maintain the same commutation relations as the original ones.

The proof is the same as for Wick's theorem. You start with the Hamiltonian and the ground state it defines, and goes on to calculate the correlation functions and contraction rules. The original nature of the operators is immaterial here, as their commutation relation algebra and the free Hamiltonian define all that is necessary for the theorem to apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!